# View centered in superview with view on top of it in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, vstack

I'm trying to achieve something that is quite easy in UIKit - one view that is always in in the center (image) and the second view (text) is on top of it with some spacing between two views. I tried many different approaches (mainly using `alignmentGuide` but nothing worked as I'd like).

code:

```swift
ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    
    VStack {
        Text("Test")
            .padding([.bottom], 20) // I want to define spacing between two views
        
        Image(systemName: "circle")
            .resizable()
            .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center, computeValue: { value in
                value[VerticalAlignment.center] + value.height
            })
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    }
}
.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```

result:

[image]

As you can see image is not perfectly centered and it actually depends on the padding value of the `Text`. Is there any way to force vertical and horizontal alignment to be centered in the superview and layout second view without affecting centered view?

Answer (score 5):

I think the “correct” way to do this is to define a custom alignment:

```
extension VerticalAlignment {
    static var custom: VerticalAlignment {
        struct CustomAlignment: AlignmentID {
            static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
                context[VerticalAlignment.center]
            }
        }
        return .init(CustomAlignment.self)
    }
}
```

Then, tell your `ZStack` to use the `custom` alignment, and use `alignmentGuide` to explicitly set the `custom` alignment on your circle:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    ZStack(alignment: .init(horizontal: .center, vertical: .custom)) {
        Color.white

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

        VStack {
            Text("Test")
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .alignmentGuide(.custom, computeValue: { $0.height / 2 })
        }
    }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can center the `Image` by moving it to `ZStack`. Then apply `.alignmentGuide` to the `Text`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)

            Text("Test")
                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { $0[.bottom] + $0.height }

            Image(systemName: "circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

---

Note that as you specify the width/height of the `Image` explicitly:

```
Image(systemName: "circle")
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
```

you can specify the `.alignmentGuide` explicitly as well:

```
.alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { $0[.bottom] + 50 }
```

Comment: making image frame bigger gives overlap with text, because they actually do not align to each other.

Comment: @Asperi True, I assumed that if OP decided to specify the frame width/height explicitly they can specify the alignmentGuide as well.

Comment: @pawello2222 it's a nice solution and I will probably stick to it for now but as Asperi noticed - it's not without a flaw. As I said in the question - I would like to have image centered in its superview and be able to align other view to it (padding or something else)

Comment: @mikro098 And this is exactly what I proposed in my answer. You *can* align everything as you wish. But in the long run I'd recommend you use [rob mayoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63304896/8697793) - it's more complicated but once you understand it, it will allow you to align views using their *relative* position. As always I suggest you read this excellent tutorial: [Alignment Guides in SwiftUI](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible alternate, using automatic space consuming feature

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)

            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Color.clear
                    .overlay(
                        Text("Test").padding([.bottom], 10),
                        alignment: .bottom)

                Image(systemName: "circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)

                Color.clear
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

*Note: before I used `Spacer()` for such purpose but with Swift 2.0 it appears spacer becomes always just a spacer, ie. nothing can be attached to it - maybe bug.*